# Rotating a mesh in Trimesh

Tags: python, geometry, rotation, transform, trimesh

I have a mesh geometry loaded into Python via TriMesh. I want a free floating camera, but I want to change the default view (of a trimesh scene) by rotating the mesh. How do I rotate a mesh or set the default view of the camera without creating a fixed camera?